# How can I get the cron daemon to send me email when a job fails with an error?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, email, cron

I have a few Ubuntu boxes that run various cron jobs daily. As far as I know, there is no postfix or sendmail installed. What's the easiest and/or best way to get cron to send me an email when one of its jobs fail with an error?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cron notifies root by default, this is local user mail delivery only.

If you want to send emails to user@gmail.com, then install postfix (defaut conf with listen on localhost only) and modifies /etc/aliases to forward emails to root to user@gmail.com.
Then run

```
postaliases /etc/aliases
```

and you're all set

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure MTA (postfix, sendmail or the debian standard: exim, etc.). It may be problematic though if you don't have public, static IP in business IP range as most other blocks are blacklisted because of spammers.

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://cronitor.io -- it's a simple cron job monitoring tool that will alert you if your job doesn't run, or takes too long to run, or finishes too quickly.